# Marketing Cloud permissions - can't export shared DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions

We've created a role that works for our business, there is one permission that we are struggling to work out. We have Data Extension permissions allowed for exporting, and shared folders are set to allow, however users are unable to export any data extension in any Shared folder, but can from DE or SF folders. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

So our issue was that we were adding standard roles along with our custom roles. According to SF support they can sometimes conflict. Strangely the conflict happened for some users and not others. We found that assigning a single role that had been tested for all the permissions we needed worked better.